# How to better understand 'aggressive' in "an aggressive critic of what he saw as unfair Japanese trade practices in the 1980s."

Tags: meaning

I'm reading a book named *Chip War: The Fight for the World's Most Critical Technology*.

When I reading below paragraph：

> Jerry Sanders : Founder and CEO of AMD; Silicon Valley’s most
> flamboyant salesman; an aggressive critic of what he saw as unfair
> Japanese trade practices in the 1980s.

I'm a bit confused about "aggressive", I fonud "aggressive" may used as "ANGRY" in above paragraph at [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/aggressive)

[image]

But see above picture the target of action is "another people". So how to better understand "aggressive"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the page you cite.  A bit further down is

> determined to win or succeed and using forceful action to win or to achieve success

Which is perhaps ill-phrased, because it cites

> an aggressive election campaign

and

> aggressive marketing tactics

both of which would use "forceful" only metaphorically.  Lots of billboards, ads, signs, and quite possibly pamphlets delivered to homes or businesses, but not actually violent.

To be an aggressive critic would be to push the criticism in many places.